# Error: Excel Destination.Connections[OleDbConnection] does not have a value for the ID property

Tags: excel, ssis, etl, sql-server-data-tools, ssis-2017

I want to write the data from SQL server in Excel destination. When executed the Data Flow Task gets failed due to these error:

> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: The "Excel Destination.Connections[OleDbConnection]" in the connection manager collection, Connections, of "Excel Destination" does not have a value for the ID property. Verify that the ConnectionManagerID property of the runtime connection object has been set for the component.
>
> [SSIS.Pipeline] Error: Excel Destination failed validation and returned error code 0xC004801C.

I have set the `Delay Validation` property of the package to `TRUE`

Comment: Is the issue solved? have you tried the suggestion below?

Answer (score 2):

This exception occurs when you didn't specify a connection manager for the Excel Destination. Double click on the Excel Destination, there is a property called **Excel Connection Manager** which allow selecting an existing Excel connection manager from the list, or creating a new connection by clicking New.

[image]

For more information on how to import data to Excel you can refer to the following links:

- [Using SSIS to Export Data to Excel](http://knowlton-group.com/using-ssis-to-export-data-to-excel/)
- [Import data from Excel or export data to Excel with SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/load-data-to-from-excel-with-ssis?view=sql-server-2017)
- [Excel Destination](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/integration-services/data-flow/excel-destination?view=sql-server-2017)

**Similar Issue link**

- [Generate dynamic Excel Worksheets with Data in SSIS](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/6c55f079-c2d5-4aae-87b1-e27ecb8a7cc4/generate-dynamic-excel-worksheets-with-data-in-ssis?forum=sqlintegrationservices)

Answer (score 0):

I resolved a similar 'does not have a value for the ID property' error by closing the destination Excel file associated with the connection, which was open on the desktop.

Error string details.

> Error at Data Flow Task [SSIS.Pipeline]: The "OData
> Source.Connections[Connection]" in the connection manager collection,
> Connections, of "OData Source" does not have a value for the ID
> property. Verify that the ConnectionManagerID property of the runtime
> connection object has been set for the component.